# Radius of Convergence for the Power Series Solution of $\ u''+(x+1)u'-u=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

> Consider the initial value problem,
>   $$u''+(x+1)u'-u=0 \ \ \ \ \ \ u(-1)=2, u'(-1)=0.$$ I wish to find the radius of convergence of the power series solution (about $x=-1$).

My attempt:

I have found that the recurrence relation is $$A_{k+2}=-\frac{(k-1)A_k}{(k+2)(k+1)} \ \ k\geq 0$$
To find the radius of convergence, I use the ratio test (where $z=x+1$),
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{A_{k+2}z^{k+2}}{A_kz^k}\right|=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{1-k}{(k+2)(k+1)}\right||z^2|=0.$$
Now by the ratio test, this converges absolutely as $0<1$. The answer I have been given states the radius of convergence is $\infty$. *Why* is this?

Comment: Take another look at the [radius of convergence using the ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius).

Comment: The $z^k$ near the end of the last line should be $|z|^2$.

Comment: thanks for the spot, fixed it

Comment: @sobi It says that "Note that r = 1/0 is interpreted as an infinite radius", Does this effectively answer my question?

Comment: @Bell I would say so!

Comment: Are there any other cases (besides $\lim_{k\to\infty}=0$) when the ratio test yields an infinite radius?

Comment: @Bell If $\alpha = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|$ is not equal to $0$, then the radius of convergence $R = \frac{1}{\alpha}$ is finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noted,
$$|z|^2 \cdot \lim_{k \to \infty} \left|\frac{1 - k}{(k + 2)(k + 1)}\right| = 0$$
for all $k$, regardless of the value of $z$. The ratio test tells us that, when this limiting ratio is strictly less than $1$, the series converges absolutely.

The logic behind this involves comparison to a geometric series. We know that a series with common ratio $r$ such that $|r| < 1$ converges. If we have a limiting ratio of $L < 1$, then the gaps between terms will eventually become less than gaps between terms of a geometric series with common ratio $\frac{L + 1}{2} < 1$. Such a geometric series converges, so the original series must converge too.

In this case, we have limiting ratio is $0$, which is an extreme case. Not only will it converge, it will converge quickly!